# OWASP ZAP-Adanced container fails to start for DAST analysis

Tags: owasp, graalvm, zap, penetration-testing

I am working on implementing an API DAST scan using `zap-advanced` provided by [secureCodeBox - ZAP Advanced](https://www.securecodebox.io/docs/scanners/zap-advanced). But the container does not start with the following error:

```
Defaulted container "zap-advanced-scan" out of: zap-advanced-scan, zap-sidecar, lurker
Error from server (BadRequest): container "zap-advanced-scan" in pod "scan-zap-advanced-api-scan-mybizservice-zs7bg-ksnrl" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
```

Following is the scan config:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: zap-advanced-scan-config
data:
  2-zap-advanced-scan.yaml: |-

    global:
      sessionName: mybizservice-zap-api-scan
      scripts:
        - name: "Alert_on_HTTP_Response_Code_Errors.js"
          enabled: true
          filePath: "/home/zap/.ZAP_D/scripts/scripts/httpsender/Alert_on_HTTP_Response_Code_Errors.js"
          engine: "Oracle Nashorn"
          type: "httpsender"
          description: "A HTTP Sender Script which will raise alerts based on HTTP Response codes."
        - name: "Alert_on_Unexpected_Content_Types.js"
          enabled: true
          filePath: "/home/zap/.ZAP_D/scripts/scripts/httpsender/Alert_on_Unexpected_Content_Types.js"
          engine: "Oracle Nashorn"
          type: "httpsender"
          description: "A HTTP Sender Script which will raise alerts based on unexpected Content-Types."

    contexts:
      - name: mybizservice-context
        url: https://abc-dev.org.cloud/
        includePaths:
          - "https://abc-dev.org.cloud/backend/payment.*"
        excludePaths:
          - ".*\\.css"
          - ".*\\.png"
          - ".*\\.jpeg"

    apis:
      - name: scb-mybizservice-api
        context: mybizservice-context
        format: openapi
        url: https://abc-dev.org.cloud/backend/payment/v3/api-docs
        hostOverride: https://abc-dev.org.cloud

     scripts:
     - name: "zap-api-authentication-script"
       enabled: true
       filePath: "/home/zap/.ZAP_D/scripts/scripts/authentication/zap-api-authentication.js"
       engine: "Graal.js"
       type: "authentication"
       description: "ZAP API AuthN script for K8s"
                
    spiders:
      - name: mybizservice-spider
        context: mybizservice-context
        url: https://abc-dev.org.cloud/backend/payment/
        failIfFoundUrlsLessThan: 0
        warnIfFoundUrlsLessThan: 0
        maxDuration: 1
        maxDepth: 5
        maxChildren: 10
        acceptCookies: true
        parseComments: true
        parseGit: false
        parseRobotsTxt: false
        parseSitemapXml: false
        parseSVNEntries: false
        postForm: true
        processForm: true
        requestWaitTime: 200
        sendRefererHeader: true
        threadCount: 2
        userAgent: "secureCodeBox / ZAP Spider"
    
    scanners:
      - name: scb-mybizservice-scan
        context: scb-mybizservice-context
        url: https://abc-dev.org.cloud/backend/payment/
        policy: "API-Minimal"
        default: 0 unlimited
        maxRuleDurationInMins: 1          
        maxScanDurationInMins: 5
        threadPerHost: 5
        delayInMs: 0
        addQueryParam: false
        handleAntiCSRFTokens: false
        injectPluginIdInHeader: false
        scanHeadersAllRequests: false
```

---

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: zap-api-authentication-script
data:
  zap-api-authentication.js: |-
    const fetch = require('node-fetch')

    const client_auth_id = "clientid1212"
    const client_auth_secret = "abcd1234-200f-4427-9c8c-48ef6789wxyz"
    let auth = "Basic " + Buffer.from(client_auth_id+":"+client_auth_secret).toString('base64')


    const params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");


    let url = "https://abc-dev.org.cloud/uaa/oauth/token"

    let headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "client_id": "clientid1212",
        "Authorization": auth,
    }

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: params,
    })
    .then( res => res.json())
        .then (token => {
            return token['access_token'];
        })
```

---

```
apiVersion: "execution.securecodebox.io/v1"
kind: Scan
metadata:
  name: "zap-advanced-api-scan-mybizservice"
  labels:
    organization: "OWASP"
spec:
  scanType: "zap-advanced-scan"
  parameters:
    - "-t"
    - " https://abc-dev.org.cloud/backend/payment/"
    - "-o"
    - "/home/securecodebox/"
  volumeMounts:
    - name: zap-advanced-scan-config
      mountPath: /home/securecodebox/configs/2-zap-advanced-scan.yaml
      subPath: 2-zap-advanced-scan.yaml
      readOnly: true
    - name: zap-api-authentication-script
      mountPath: /home/zap/.ZAP_D/scripts/scripts/authentication/zap-api-authentication.js
      subPath: zap-api-authentication.js
  volumes:
    - name: zap-advanced-scan-config
      configMap:
        name: zap-advanced-scan-config
    - name: zap-api-authentication-script
      configMap:
        name: zap-api-authentication-script
```

If I remove the authentication script, API scan executes with `FINISHED` status but with zero alerts. I believe it is so because ZAP requires API authentication to proceed with analyses.
Hence I added the Authentication script but faced the issue mentioned above.

I would be grateful for any help here.

Comment: This isn't a ZAP issue. That docker is produced by a third party.

Comment: The supported ways to automate ZAP are listed on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/ For anything else you are best talking directly to the people who maintain whatever you are using.